# Unexpected token { in JSON или как заставить это работать?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Всю ночь бьюсь с этой проблемой и вот решил написать сюда, ибо ну капец уже не знаю че делать.

В общем в php все просто. Нужен список, получили список.

```
$userData = $database->select("account", [
                "user_id",
                "username",
                "first_name",
                "last_name"
            ],[
                "referer_id" => $user_id
            ]);

            foreach ($userData as $data) {
                echo '<div>".data["first_name"]." ".data["last_name"]." ".data["username"]."</div>';
            }
```

Но как только я решил подгружать список аяксом, у меня либо подгружается последний из списка либо ошибка указанная в заголовке `Unexpected token { in JSON` Это ошибка ругается на то, что если я помещаю `echo json_encode($data);`внутрь цикла, то при `var userdata = JSON.parse(data);`  я получаю список объектов которые не разделяются запятым.

```
$userData = $database->select("account", [
                "user_id",
                "username",
                "first_name",
                "last_name"
            ],[
                "referer_id" => $user_id
            ]);

            foreach ($userData as $data) {
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
```

```
{"user_id":"14","username":"daniel","first_name":"Daniel","last_name":"Test"}
//здесь начинает ругаться, и так между всеми объектами.
{"user_id":"15","username":"johndoe","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}
```

Однако если я выношу `echo json_encode($data);` за пределы цикла то получаю только последнего выбранного в базе.

```
$userData = $database->select("account", [
                "user_id",
                "username",
                "first_name",
                "last_name"
            ],[
                "referer_id" => $user_id
            ]);

            foreach ($userData as $data) {
                
            }

            $response = [
               "user_id => $data["user_id"],
               "first_name" => $data["first_name"],
               "last_name" => $data["last_name"],
               "username" => $data["username"]
            ];

            echo json_encode($response);
```

```
var userdata = JSON.parse(data);

$.each(userdata,function(key,data) {
     console.log('Name = ' + userdata.first_name + ' Family = '+ userdata.last_name +' Username = '+userdata.username);
    });
```

Итого:
Как правильно сделать, чтобы получать такой же список как я получал когда использовал `php foreach`? Нужно ли как-то объединять `JSON`объекты или подставлять между ними запятую, или все намного проще?

---

В общем добавил тип `dataType: 'json'` к запросу и теперь получаю массив с объектами. Только не понятно как его теперь перебрать через `for (var key in data)`

```
6: {user_id: "9", user_register: "2021-06-21 20:41:07", username: "daniel5"... email: "daniel5@mail.com", first_name: "Daniel 5", …}
7: {user_id: "11", user_register: "2021-06-21 20:43:04", username: "daniel7", email: "daniel7@mail.com", first_name: "Daniel 7", …}
8: {user_id: "12", user_register: "2021-06-21 20:43:18", username: "daniel8", email: "daniel8@mail.com", first_name: "Daniel 8", …}
9: {user_id: "13", user_register: "2021-06-21 20:43:31", username: "daniel9", email: "daniel9@mail.com", first_name: "Daniel9", ...}
```

Comment: ну если закатываете в json список, то нужно закатывать его в массив: `[ {...}, {...}, ... ]` надо брать не по частям, а целиком `echo json_encode($userData)`

Comment: В этом и странность. Medoo поддерживает возврат в JSON и казалось бы должно работать так как вы пишите, но в таком случае я получаю undefined

Comment: Нет не так! Да при```echo json_encode($userData)``` я получаю все объекты но при ```var userdata = JSON.parse(data);``` undefined

Comment: тогда наверное надо перепроверить javascript, как там извлекается data из ответа сервера

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос .т.к в комментариях много не помещается.

Comment: Вложенным циклом. Внешний цикл по массиву, внутренний по ключам текущего элемента.

Comment: Сделал так ```$.each(data,function(key,userdata) {}``` заработало. Не знаю насколько это правильно но работает.

Comment: `data.forEach(userData => { console.log('Name = ' + userdata.first_name ... })` 
`vanilla javascript`, развиваясь семимильными шагами, списывает `jquery` в утиль:). Это так, на заметку. Хотя...

Comment: чем не устраивает просто `json_encode($userData )` вместо foreach?

Comment: Да ``data.forEach(userData =>``` устроило)

Answer (score -1):

> В общем добавил тип dataType: 'json' к запросу и теперь получаю массив
> с объектами. Только не понятно как его теперь перебрать через for (var
> key in data)

Как вариант можно так обработать:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data))
```

Тут более подробно написано:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries